# $p$-subgroup is a proper subset of its normalizer

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, proof-explanation, group-actions, normal-subgroups

I'm trying to understand the following proof from Kurzweil-Stellmacher:

[image]

> How does $PgP=Pg$ imply $gPg^{-1}=P$?

**Transcription of image:**

**3.1.10** Let $P$ be a $p$-subgroup of $G$ and $p$ be a divisor of $|G:P|$. Then $P<N_G(P)$.

*Proof.* By 3.1.1 (c) $P$ acts on the set $\Omega$ of right cosets $Pg, g\in G$, by right multiplication, and $$|\Omega| = |G:P|\equiv 0\pmod p.$$
From 3.1.7 we get (with $P$ in place of $G$):
$$|C_\Omega(P)|\equiv |\Omega|\equiv 0\pmod p.$$
Moreover $C_\Omega(P)\neq\emptyset$ since $P\in C_\Omega(P)$. Hence there exists $Pg \in C_\Omega(P)$ such that $P\neq Pg$. This implies $g\notin P$ and $PgP=Pg$. Thus $gPg^{-1}=P$ and $g\in N_G(P)\setminus P$.

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text.

Comment: [Here is an explanation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742) for why you should not use images this way.

Comment: @Shaun Is this fine?

Comment: Yes, that's better!

Comment: If $PgP =Pg$, then multipkying by $g^{-1}$ on the right we get $P(gPg^{-1})=P$, which means $gPg^{-1}=P$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin How do you get the last equality from the second?

Comment: $|HK||H\cap K| =|H|\,|K|$, so the intersection must equal $P$.